# Multile Ignite Client with Cluser Singleton Service Connect to Remote Ignite Server Failed to marshal discovery data

Tags: ignite

I have 2 Ignite server, and when I create a ignite client,
it will connect to the two server and it works fine with no error.

In the ignite client java code, it create a cluster singleton service

But if i create a second ignite client with the same code, the 
client will also call the function to create the cluster singleton service(i think ignite may know this service has one already, and will not create again, correct me if i am wrong), and in the one of the server, it dumps the following errors(another is fine):

```html
[02:05:30,912][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to marshal discovery data 
[comp=0, data=DiscoveryData [nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c, items=[DiscoveryDataItem 
[routineId=6be10471-bdfb-47e0-881a-aa9cf285cead, prjPred=IgniteAllNodesPredicate [], 
hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2 [rmtFilterFactory=com.test.simple.IgniteMatchClusterSingletonService$3@39812ce8, 
rmtFilterFactoryDep=null, types=0], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true], DiscoveryDataItem
 [routineId=c0582fdc-0539-4c41-8238-f15d426af475, prjPred=IgniteAllNodesPredicate [], 
hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler [cacheName=datastructures_ATOMIC_PARTITIONED_0@default-ds-group, 
rmtFilter=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.datastructures.CacheDataStructuresManager$QueueHeaderPredicate@4e5687a1, 
rmtFilterDep=null, internal=true, notifyExisting=true, oldValRequired=true, sync=false, ignoreExpired=true,
 taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=false, locCache=false, keepBinary=false, ackBuf=CacheContinuousQueryAcknowledgeBuffer
 [size=0, updateCntrs={}, topVers=[]], cacheId=474336146, initTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=10], 
nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false, asyncCb=false, nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c, 
routineId=c0582fdc-0539-4c41-8238-f15d426af475], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true], DiscoveryDataItem 
[routineId=a2ad72c7-cd07-4fd5-bb51-adf33d344238, prjPred=EqualsClusterNodeIdPredicate 
[nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c], hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, 
rmtFilter=null, rmtFilterDep=null, internal=true, notifyExisting=true, oldValRequired=true, sync=false, 
ignoreExpired=true, taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=true, locCache=false, keepBinary=false, 
ackBuf=CacheContinuousQueryAcknowledgeBuffer [size=0, updateCntrs={}, topVers=[]], cacheId=-2100569601, 
initTopVer=null, nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false, asyncCb=false, nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c,
 routineId=a2ad72c7-cd07-4fd5-bb51-adf33d344238], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize object: DiscoveryData [nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c,
 items=[DiscoveryDataItem [routineId=6be10471-bdfb-47e0-881a-aa9cf285cead, prjPred=IgniteAllNodesPredicate [],
 hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2 [rmtFilterFactory=com.test.simple.IgniteMatchClusterSingletonService$3@39812ce8, 
rmtFilterFactoryDep=null, types=0], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true], DiscoveryDataItem 
[routineId=c0582fdc-0539-4c41-8238-f15d426af475, prjPred=IgniteAllNodesPredicate [], hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler 
[cacheName=datastructures_ATOMIC_PARTITIONED_0@default-ds-group, 
rmtFilter=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.datastructures.CacheDataStructuresManager$QueueHeaderPredicate@4e5687a1, 
rmtFilterDep=null, internal=true, notifyExisting=true, oldValRequired=true, sync=false, ignoreExpired=true, 
taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=false, locCache=false, keepBinary=false, ackBuf=CacheContinuousQueryAcknowledgeBuffer 
[size=0, updateCntrs={}, topVers=[]], cacheId=474336146, initTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=10], 
nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false, asyncCb=false, nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c, 
routineId=c0582fdc-0539-4c41-8238-f15d426af475], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true], DiscoveryDataItem 
[routineId=a2ad72c7-cd07-4fd5-bb51-adf33d344238, prjPred=EqualsClusterNodeIdPredicate [nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c], 
hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, rmtFilter=null, rmtFilterDep=null, internal=true, notifyExisting=true, 
oldValRequired=true, sync=false, ignoreExpired=true, taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=true, locCache=false, keepBinary=false, 
ackBuf=CacheContinuousQueryAcknowledgeBuffer [size=0, updateCntrs={}, topVers=[]], cacheId=-2100569601, initTopVer=null, 
nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false, asyncCb=false, nodeId=bb2beed3-38e9-4134-a898-b4aab8705c8c, 
routineId=a2ad72c7-cd07-4fd5-bb51-adf33d344238], bufSize=1, interval=0, autoUnsubscribe=true]]]
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.marshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:103)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:70)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.marshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:117)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:58)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.marshalData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:311)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.marshalGridNodeData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:87)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.collectExchangeData(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1897)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processNodeAddedMessage(ServerImpl.java:4173)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2706)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2519)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerAdapter.body(ServerImpl.java:6707)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2602)
 at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.test.simple.IgniteMatchClusterSingletonService$2
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2.writeExternal(CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2.java:157)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$DiscoveryDataItem.writeExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1853)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.writeCollection(IgniteUtils.java:1754)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$DiscoveryData.writeExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1772)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
 at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.marshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:98)
 ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is clearly shown in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.test.simple.IgniteMatchClusterSingletonService$2
```

There is an anonymous class (`com.test.simple.IgniteMatchClusterSingletonService$2`) that is not `Serializable`, but gets serialized along with the service instance.

If this is expected, then you need to make sure this class does implement `Serializable`. Otherwise, change the code so that instance of this class is not sent across network.

In general, I would recommend to avoid using anonymous classes or lambdas for anything that can be serialized. They typically contain a link to enclosing class which makes it more difficult to understand what is serialized and what is not. Switch to inner static classes to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, yes i realize it be the issue the anonymous class could not be serialized, i have use the continous query in a ignite clustersingleton service, so it will be serialzied and transfer to other nodes, i have ref the example in:https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries, it use the anonmous class to do the query, i am trying to conver this anonymous class to static, if it could work?  Also and i wonderto know if i could set peerClassLoadingEnabled to false and copy the jar file to each node's ignite classpath is another way or not? Thanks

Comment: Class has to be explicitly deployed on local classpath for continuous queries. Peer class loading does not fully work for them. But this is not related to your original issue, whatever is serialized (either anonymous or static class) must implement `Serializable`. I would recommend to go with static, but that doesn't fix the problem by itself.